# Can't install Tensorflow, because of Metadata error

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

**EDIT: I already upgraded pip before initializing this process**

I'm kind of **stuck at this part where you have to use Protobuf to install Tensorflow**. I did everything as those instructors in the Youtube video. I saw multiple videos, documents but none could help me out. Please help me...

The codes which were given in the terminal are down below

```
sudo apt install protobuf
```

After this **I cloned the Tensorflow/models from the github repository** and then I typed these as shown in that video

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models

utkarsh@ubuntu:~/tensorflow/models/research$ protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

Then I **copied the setup.py into object_detection** subfolder as per instructions

```
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
```

and finally I **ran the setup.py**

```
python -m pip install .
```

This was the error code I received, and now I'm stuck

```
utkarsh@ubuntu:~/tensorflow/models/research$ python -m pip install .
Processing /home/utkarsh/tensorflow/models/research
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "/home/utkarsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import Distribution
        File "/home/utkarsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 35, in <module>
          from ._importlib import metadata
        File "/home/utkarsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_importlib.py", line 28, in <module>
          disable_importlib_metadata_finder(metadata)
        File "/home/utkarsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_importlib.py", line 19, in disable_importlib_metadata_finder
          for ob in sys.meta_path
        File "/home/utkarsh/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_importlib.py", line 20, in <listcomp>
          if isinstance(ob, importlib_metadata.MetadataPathFinder)
      AttributeError: module 'importlib_metadata' has no attribute 'MetadataPathFinder'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494526/jupiter-notebook-run-error-attributeerror-module-importlib-metadata-has-no-a)

Comment: Also check [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#protobuf-installation-compilation) link to install object deletction API.

Answer (score 0):

I also received a metadata error on installation of TF2, was able to resolve by creating a new virtual env.

environment summary: win11, anaconda, visual studio 2022, cuda 12.3.0, cudnn 8.9.4, protobuf 24.4

created a virtual env in conda, python was 3.11, resolved by creating a new virtual environment, python = 3.9